# Problems with ODE and PyODE

Tags: python, pyode

I have been working with CUDA on ubuntu and now I need to use the ODE - Open Dynamics Engine - tied together with PyODE also on Ubuntu 14.04. I think the OS versions does not really help on the issue.

Well, I have searched a lot about how to install the ODE and respectively the PyODE. The first result shown was this one: sudo apt-get install python-pyode on terminal, but it doesn't work at all.

Then I downloaded the sources ODE and PyODE and installed manually. The installation works out perfectly but when I try to compile a sample program I got this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wagner/workspace/PyODE/trying.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ode
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ode.so: undefined symbol: dMassSetCappedCylinderTotal
```

This attempt was made under the IDE Eclipse.

Thus, I've tried to type something on IDLE and I got this:

```
>>> import ode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import ode
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ode.so: undefined symbol: dMassSetCappedCylinderTotal
```

I also tried to open this file 'ode.so', but I cannot.